# How do I create a catchall async error handler in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express.js and I am trying to create a catchall async error handler.
Say I have three routes which all may throw error,

```
const app = express()

app.get('/user', async function(req,res) {
   const res = await getUsers()
})

app.get('/questions', async function(req,res) {
   const res = await getQuestions()
})

app.get('/answers', async function(req,res) {
   const res = await getAnswers()
})
```

in these three routes, all getXX function might throw error.
I want to have just one async handler for all routes. Something like this

```
app.use(asyncHandler)
```

so I don't have to try/catch every place that may throw error. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to write async/await in try/catch block. because await only takes resolve output from promise if error throw from await function it handles by the catch block.

In catch block next(error) called which go throw all following middleware until it is not found error handling minddler.

```
const app = require("../../Reference/node-post-demo/app")

app.get('/user', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const res = await getUsers();
    return res.json(res);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.get('/questions', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const res = await getQuestions()
    return res.json(res);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.get('/answers', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const res = await getAnswers()
    return res.json(res);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.use(async (error, req, res) => {
  //here, your error hendling code
})
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. The code you provide means that I have to provide try/catch block for every async controllers, which is what I am trying to avoid. I want to wrap the handler into one and avoid duplicate codes

Comment: It's best practice to use try/catch for async/await. You just need to pass the error into next() and all error handle from one place.